# Jquery - mouseenter pushing content down

Tags: jquery

really sorry if this has been asked before but I have searched high and low for an asnwer and now found one...

On my website, I have a "footer" and a "bottom". When the user hovers over the bottom part of the website, I want the footer to appear. I have been able to do that (code below) successfully. However, when the user hovers over the "bottom" div, the footer expands downwards and therefore the user has to scroll down to see what has appeared. not a HUGE problem but it's not really great for the user. it would be much better if the site pushed up when the footer was shown. Does anyone know how I can do this? Is it just a CSS tweek to the footer div? thank you in advance all. great forum this is!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#bottom").mouseenter(function(){
      $("#footer").stop(true,true).slideDown( function(){
        $("#bottom").addClass("open");
      });
  });
  $("#footer, #bottom").mouseleave( function(){
    $("#footer").stop(true,true).delay(1000).slideUp( function(){
      $("#bottom").removeClass("open");
    });
  });
  $("#footer").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#footer").stop(true,true).slideDown();
  });
});


#footer {
display:none;
height: 200px;
}
#bottom
{
height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 200);
```

inside the callback of the slideDown function.
This will scroll the document to the bottom.

**See comments:**

```
 var event = window.setInterval(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 50);
 }, 50);
 $("#footer").stop(true,true).slideDown( function(){
    $("#bottom").addClass("open");
    window.clearInterval(event);
  });
```

Comment: Wow thank you that's worked a TREAT!
Thanks for quick response too. 
Absolutely love this forum. No elitism and great answers of genuinely helpful people. Cheers!

Comment: I was going to say, although it works really well, it still kinda makes the page JUMP and it'd be nice for it to be smooth and just move it up with it but thank you, that's a javascript thing and nothing we can do, right?

Comment: Well, you can do that but it might eat up some performance. I'll edit the anser with a sample code... - updated - This might contain syntax errors tho' - It will do a scroll every 50 ms)